espero alguien me pueda colaborar, como agregar en combo box dependientes?
Tengan un excelente dia tarde o noche espero que alguien me pueda orientar ya que ando aprendiendo solo mirando videos de YouTube y la verdad he echo bastante, pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer lo siguiente digamos que en la columna "A" tenga modelos específicos supongamos celulares entonces en esa columna tengo Samsung Nokia Alcatel etc. en la columna "B" tengo Samsung y en las filas los modelos de Samsung en la columna "c" tengo Nokia y en la fila los modelos y así sucesivamente lo siguiente que deseo digamos Samsung saco un nuevo modelo que sea realizar un formulario para agregar producto entonces selecciono la marca de la lista que tengo y que solo en esa columna me agregue el modelo nuevo sin afectar filas y demás columnas... que Nokia saco uno nuevo solamente que me agregue el modelo del Nokia sin afectar las demás filas y columnas y supongamos que llego un modelo nuevo que no esta la lista "PATOJITO" entonces que agregue el nombre y automáticamente coloque el nombre de la marca en la ultima fila de la columna "A" y nuevamente el nombre en su respectiva columna vacía para que cuando coloque el modelo empiece desde la fila 2 columna la nueva que se agregue no se si me di a entender y bueno espero recibir respuesta no se mucho del tema pero aprendo es la idea

La verdad es que no se entiende, tú dices que cuando agregas elementos eso afecta a filas y columnas ¿a qué te refieres?.- Además no me queda claro si tu pregunta tiene relación con la programación, porque de eso va este sitio

tienes un correo donde te pueda enviar lo que estoy realizado para ver si puedes entenderme un poco mejor

Lo que quieres hacer no se puede hacer con fórmulas, y menos si quieres emplear formularios. Tú tienes "listas" de los productos de cada marca y por otro lado tienes una lista de marcas. Lo que quieres son 2 cosas: 1) poder agregar nuevos productos a la lista de una marca específica 2) Si la marca no existe, que se cree una nueva "lista" en blanco de esa marca.
Está claro que quieres construir como una especie de base de datos y Excel no es un programa apto para hacer bases de datos. Dicho esto, si de verdad quieres seguir con tu idea tal cual, tendrás que codificar una macro en VBA.
